# How to standardize labels in a python list?

Tags: python, list

I am trying to analyse conversations and require a method of standardizing speaker labels. Each conversation is a list of sublists, each sublist comprising two strings: one for the ID of the speaker, and another for the actual utterance:

```
myconvo = [['bob','hello alice'],['alice','hello bob'],['bob','goodbye alice'],['alice','goodbye bob']]
```

Ultimately what i want to end up with is something like the following, where speaker labels have been standardized:

```
myconvo = [['speaker1','hello alice'],['speaker2','hello bob'],['speaker1','goodbye alice'],['speaker2','goodbye bob']]
```

I'm at a slight loss how to proceed, given that each conversation will have different speakers.

So far, I have gotten as far as identifying...

```
# empty list to store speaker labels
speakers = set()

# iterate through convo adding speaker names
for sub in myconvo:
    if sub[0] not in speakers:
        speakers.add(sub[0])

# convert to list to access index (where position 0 will be the first speaker, position 1 will be second speaker etc.)
speakers = list(speakers)
```

I'm unsure where to go next, or even if there is a shorter way around this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
myconvo = [['bob','hello alice'],['alice','hello bob'],['bob','goodbye alice'],['alice','goodbye bob']]

speakers = {}
count = 1
# geeting the unique user name and assigning speaker numbers to them
for i in myconvo:
    if i[0] not in speakers:
        speakers.update({i[0]:'speaker{}'.format(count)})
        count+=1

# changing the name with the speaker number
for i in range(len(myconvo)):
    name = myconvo[i][0]
    myconvo[i][0] = speakers[name]

print(myconvo)
```

output

```
[['speaker1', 'hello alice'], ['speaker2', 'hello bob'], ['speaker1', 'goodbye alice'], ['speaker2', 'goodbye bob']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try maintaining a `dict` that maps each speaker to its standardized name:

```
def standardize(conv):
    speakers = {}
    i = 1
    end_conv = []
    for speaker, sentence in conv: # iterate over speakers
        if speaker not in speakers:
            speakers[speaker] = f"speaker{i}"
            i += 1
        end_conv.append([speakers[speaker], sentence])
    return end_conv


>>> standardize(myconvo)
[['speaker1', 'hello alice'], ['speaker2', 'hello bob'], ['speaker1', 'goodbye alice'], ['speaker2', 'goodbye bob']]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
myconvo = [['bob','hello alice'],['alice','hello bob'],['bob','goodbye alice'],['alice','goodbye bob']]

speakers = set([x[0] for x in myconvo])

speaker_ids = {speaker: i + 1 for i, speaker in enumerate(speakers)}

myconvo = [[f"speaker{speaker_ids[x[0]]}", x[1]] for x in myconvo]

print(myconvo)
```

Gives:

```
[['speaker1', 'hello alice'], ['speaker2', 'hello bob'], ['speaker1', 'goodbye alice'], ['speaker2', 'goodbye bob']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You are on a right track by creating a set of speakers, although you can simplify it a bit further:

```py
speakers = {sub[0] for sub in myconvo}
```

then you need to assign their "nicks", e.g.

```py
nicks = {
    original_name: f'speaker{i}'
    for i, original_name in enumerate(speakers):    
}
```

afterwards its straightforward to iterate through your conversations and replace the names with nicks

```py
for conv in myconvo:
   conv[0] = nicks[conv[0]]
```